# What's the expression meaning violate someone's interests?

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests

I used to think that, for example, "He moved her cheese", would mean that he violate and threatens her interests. (I believe this expression comes from the popular book)

Today I found out that probably I have been wrong.
Could any native English speakers help me out?

If this expression (someone moved someone else's cheese) doesn't mean what I thought, what does it mean?
and what are the popular expressions that mean to say "threaten's someone else's interests"?

Let me give another example: The unification of Germany in the 19th century threatens the interests of France and England. Could I say that Germany moved the cheese of France and England?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ruining something for someone else (spoils of war?)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/102710/ruining-something-for-someone-else-spoils-of-war) (being a spoil-sport / dog in the manger)

Comment: No I don't think so. Let me give another example: The unification of Germany in the 19th century threatens the interests of France and England. Could I say that Germany moved the cheese of France and England?

Comment: What's wrong with **threatened the interests**?

Comment: How about “step on their toes”?  I would not use “move their cheese” because it is strongly associated with a book about which I know next to nothing.